# What does it mean in this sentence of change-of-variable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I totally can't get what Fitzpatrick said in his "*Advanced Calculus*" in the section of change-of-variable. Before showing that paragraph, let me first give some of the previous paragraph:

[image]

OK, and below is the sentence I don't understand (with red underline). As the answer below mentioned, if I understand correctly, that is due to $\Psi(K\setminus K_{\epsilon})=\Psi(K)\setminus\Psi(K_{\epsilon})$. However, here the $\Psi$ is no longer one-to-one on $K$ (notice that the author **redefined** the $K$ in the context), so why is $\Psi(K\setminus K_{\epsilon})=\Psi(K)\setminus\Psi(K_{\epsilon})$? Or does the equality hold by other reason?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply addition of integrals over disjoint domains: $$\int_{\Phi(K)}f(x,y)dxdy = \int_{\Phi(K/K_{\epsilon})}f(x,y)dxdy+\int_{\Phi(K_{\epsilon})}f(x,y)dxdy$$ and the same for the polar coordinate counterpart. Then there is cancellation due to the theorem $19.12$ applied to $K_{\epsilon}$ and the equality is justified.

Comment: I see! That is because $\Phi(K/K_{\epsilon})=\Phi(K)/\Phi(K_{\epsilon})$, since $\Phi$ is injective.

Comment: Wait... but here the $\Psi$ is not one-to-one, since $K$ can touch the boundary of $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: What are you talking about? The author said either $\theta_1 = 0$ or $\theta_2 = 2\pi$. This still preserve the smoothness of $\varPhi.$

Comment: Isn't the author mean $r_1=0 \vee \theta_1=0 \vee \theta_2=0$, which is a "inclusive-or"? (Namely, it's possible that these three can simultaneously true.) English is not my native language..

Comment: it means $r_1 = 0, \theta_1 = 0, \theta_2 <2\pi$ or $r_1 = 0, \theta_2 = 2\pi, \theta_1>0.$